# Event listener on form doesn't fire when I press submit/play

Tags: javascript, function, module, dom-events

I want to make form submit the name of playerOne and playerTwo, but I seem to can't figure it out when I listen for submit event on form it doesn't fire it. In snippet bellow is all my code.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("Doesnt work")
    })
```

```js
// player factory...
const playerFactory = (name, mark) => {
  const playTurn = (event, currentPlayer) => {
    const id = boardObject.cells.indexOf(event.target);
    boardObject.boardArray[id] = currentPlayer;
    boardObject.render();
  };

  return {
    playTurn, name, mark
  };
};

// Gameboard object...
const boardObject = (() => {
  let boardArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

  const cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
  // displays the content of the boardArray...
  const render = () => {
    boardArray.forEach((mark, idx) => {
      cells[idx].textContent = boardArray[idx];
    });
  };

  const checkWin = (currentPlayer) => {
    const winArraysCombinations = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6],
    ];

    return winArraysCombinations.some((combination) => {
      return combination.every((index) => {
        return boardArray[index].includes(currentPlayer);
      });
    });
  };

  const isDraw = (playerOne, playerTwo) => {
    return boardArray.every((cell) => {
      return cell.includes(playerOne) || cell.includes(playerTwo);
    });
  };

  return {
    boardArray,
    render,
    cells,
    checkWin,
    isDraw,
  };
})();

// Display controller ...
const displayController = (() => {
  const player = playerFactory();
  const playerOneName = document.querySelector('#playerx');
  const playerTwoName = document.querySelector('#playero');
  const resetButton = document.querySelector('.reset_button');
  const formdiv = document.querySelector('.input_form');
  
  const gameBoard = document.querySelector(".game_board");
  const form = document.querySelector('.player_info');
  let playerOne;
  let playerTwo ;
  let currentPlayer;
  

  const switchPlayer = () => {
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer === playerOne ? playerTwo : playerOne;
  };

  gameBoard.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.classList.contains("cell")) {
      if (event.target.textContent === "") {
        event.target.textContent = currentPlayer;
        player.playTurn(event, currentPlayer);
        if (boardObject.checkWin(currentPlayer)) {
          console.log(currentPlayer + " is winner!");
        } else if (boardObject.isDraw(playerOne, playerTwo)) {
          console.log("draw");
        } else {
          switchPlayer();
        }
      }
    }

    const init = () => {
      if (playerOneName.value !== '' && playerTwoName !== '' ) {
        playerOne = playerFactory(playerOneName.value, 'X');
        playerTwo = playerFactory(playerTwoName.value, 'O');
        currentPlayer = playerOne;
      };
    }

    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("Doesnt work")
    })
    
    
      // if (playerOneName.value !== '' && playerTwoName.value !== '') {
      //   init();
      //   console.log(playerOne)
      // } else {
      //   window.location.reload();
      // }
    

    

    return { currentPlayer, playerOne, playerTwo, init };
  });
})();
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: #BEE9E8;
}

header {
    background: #1B4965;
    text-align: center;
    color: #62B6CB;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}



.game_board {
    display: grid;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: 5px solid #1B4965;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.cell {
    border: 5px solid #1B4965;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #62b6cb;
    color:#1b4965;
    font-size:4em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.player_info {
    color:#1B4965;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.input_form {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.player_group {
    margin-top:20px;
}

input { 
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #1A4965;
    color: #62B6CB;
    
}

input::placeholder {
    color: #62b6cb;
}

#reset {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #1A4965;
    color: #62b6cb;
}

.reset_button {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.submitButton {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding:5px;
    width: 100px;
    color:#62b6cb;
    background: #1A4965;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Tic - Tac - Toe<br>The Odin Project</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="input_form">
        <form class="player_info">
            <div class="player_group">
                <label for="playerx">Player X:</label>
                <input type="text" id="playerx" name="playerx" placeholder="Name of player X">
            </div>

            <div class="player_group">
                <label for="playero">Player O:</label>
                <input type="text" id="playero" name="playero" placeholder="Name of player O">
            </div>
            <div><input type="submit" class="submitButton"  value="Play !"></div>
        </form>
    </div> 
        

        
        <div class="game_board hidden">
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="reset_button hidden">
            <button id="reset">Restart the game!</button>
        </div>
        
    



    <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is *where* the event listener is being added - right now, you have it within the gameBoard **click** event. Since that event only runs once the gameBoard has been clicked upon, and the gameBoard isn't yet visible, the click event cannot fire, and the listener never gets added to form.

If you just want it attached from the outset (you probably do) - just move the `form.addEventListener()` block outside the `gameBoard.addEventlistener()` block, say just after the closing "});" in the second-to-last line of code on your javascript file.